# How to POST a Form with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-forms

In my login.html I have

```
<div class="form-login">
<h4>Welcome back.</h4>
<input type="text" id="userName" ng-model="user.username"
       class="form-control input-sm chat-input" placeholder="username" />
</br>
<input type="text" id="userPassword" ng-model="user.password"
       class="form-control input-sm chat-input" placeholder="password" />
</br>
<div class="wrapper">
<span class="group-btn">     
    <a href="#!/events/add" class="btn btn-primary btn-md">login <i class="fa fa-sign-in"></i></a>
</span>
```

and I need to call the login function in users.controller which is:

```
    $scope.login = function(){
        $http.post('/login',$scope.user).then(function(response){
            window.location.href='#/add_event';
        });
    }
```

How do I go about this? Do I use something like ng-submit="login()"?

Comment: Read [AngularJS Developer Reference - Forms](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms).

Comment: You can use one of the following two ways to specify what javascript method should be called when a form is submitted:

[ngSubmit](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSubmit) directive on the form element, OR 
[ngClick](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClick) directive on the first button or input field of type submit (input[type=submit]).See [AngularJS  `form` Directive API Reference -Submitting a form](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/form#submitting-a-form-and-preventing-the-default-action)

Comment: *"use something like ng-submit"* ... yes exactly